# Install IBM Qiskit for quantum computer simulation

Tags: qiskit

I am having trouble uploading qiskit to my Ananconda3 environment.  I follow these steps without any problem. In Anaconda3 shell

1. conda create -n ENV_NAME python=3
2. conda activate ENV_NAME
3. pip install qiskit
4. pip install qiskit[visualization]

When I check the modules with conda list, qiskit is not to be found. Other modules such as numpy, matplotlib, etc. are present.

Any suggestions?  On my previous Windows based PC, I was able to download everything without any  problems.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to check that you're installing everything correctly. I've had this when using a different local image/dev instance and didn't realise I didn't have the updated packages. Use `pip list` to double check.

- `pip list --outdated` shows any of your packages that have newer versions available for upgrade, in case your local instance is running older versions.
- `pip list --local` focuses only on packages you specifically installed, not system-level dependencies, which i find useful for seeing what I specifically installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  `pip list` since you installed with pip